# Error when using qgis2web plugin

Tags: qgis2web

I was trying to start using qgis2web plugin to make webgis for the first time, but when i click "create web map", i got this error message:

```
WARNING Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/Users/UAV/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\qgis2web.py", line 60, in run
                self.dlg = MainDialog(self.iface)
              File "C:/Users/UAV/AppData/Roaming/QGIS/QGIS3\profiles\default/python/plugins\qgis2web\maindialog.py", line 160, in __init__
                QgsProject.instance().cleared.connect(self.reject)
            AttributeError: 'QgsProject' object has no attribute 'cleared'
```

Could anybody here help me to solve because I'm very new to this.

Comment: What QGIS Version are you using ?

Comment: i'm using qgis 3.0.1

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for reporting this qgis2web error. Stack Exchange is more a "how-to" kind of place, rather than a "this software is broken" one. If you have the time, can you report this problem by creating a new issue at https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/? It will help a great deal - it's bug reports like these which really help improve open-source software.

A warning in advance, though: you'll probably be asked to give more details on how to recreate the error, and even to upload your data. This is because a developer's first aim in fixing a bug is to experience it themselves. If I can't recreate the bug myself, it's almost impossible for me to fix it.

Anyway, let's hope we get this one sorted. QGIS2 is no longer supported, and qgis2web2 is no longer being developed or bugfixed, so we really need to get it working for you in QGIS3. It definitely looks like you've uncovered something which should have been changed when qgis2web was updated to work with QGIS3, but was missed.

Thanks again for the input.

Answer (score 1):

I tried qgis2web in QGIS 2.18 and it worked well. From the error can be seen that QgsProject does not have "cleared" attribute. Could be the plugin is not ported properly into QGIS 3. So if you really want to do this, try to use the plugin for QGIS 2.x instead.